# multiple thermostat boiler connection

Tags: wiring, heating, thermostat

I have a boiler system with thermostats and valves for three floors. before i changed the boiler what ever thermostat called for heat worked for that floor. Now all thermostats have to be on or calling for heat. This makes the top floor hot and barely any temperature change in the basement. I see how this helps with gas efficiency but I only want to heat each floor differently. I dont remember a lot about the wiring on the old system. What do I need to rewire to put it back to what it was.?  Thanks for any help or input.

Comment: Can you provide a wiring diagram for the boiler, and what make/model the various zone valves and thermostats are?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change out the boiler yourself or have it done by a contractor? It sound like you/they hooked up the thermostats in series instead of in parallel for the boiler "on". If you did it, go back and correct it ..... if they did it, get them back and tell them the problem. Good luck